# Как сделать чтобы определенный код/функция срабатывал при запуске/закрытии бота Aiogram 3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Во втором aiogram'e есть два параметра при старте поллинга и запуске вебхука, это `on_startup` и `on_shudown`, которые срабатывают при запуске и завершении бота.
Как сделать это на третьей версии aiogram'a так как там, нету таких параметров при запуске?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import asyncio

from loader import dp, bot


async def on_startup(dispatcher):
    print("Бот запущен")


async def main():
    # способ для пропуска старых апдейтов для 3 версии айограма
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True) 
    # собственно способ зарегистрировать функцию которая сработает при запуске бота
    dp.startup.register(on_startup)
    # в allowed_updates можно передать вызов метода resolve_used_update_types() от диспетчера, 
    # который пройдёт по всем роутерам, узнает, хэндлеры на какие типы есть в коде, 
    # и попросить Telegram присылать апдейты только про них
    # короче просто делайте так же
    await dp.start_polling(bot, allowed_updates=dp.resolve_used_update_types())

@dp.message()
async def random_handler(message: types.Message):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```